# Laravel 5 Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi i have a problem with this code.

This is the view

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
<h2>All Todo Lists</h2>
<ul>
<?php
@foreach ($todo_lists as $list)
<li>{{$list->name}}</li>
@endforeach
?>
</ul>
@stop
```

This is the controller (only method index that i actually use

```
public function index()
{

    $todo_lists = TodoList::all();
   return view('todos/index')->with('todo_lists', $todo_lists);

}

public function create()
{
 return "Create a new list";
}
```

This is the model

```
class TodoList extends Eloquent{
   protected $tabel = 'todo_lists';
}
```

I have a database with todo_lists table which have some information like id and name that i want to display. But actually th view returns me a blank page. It seems that the problem was in the controller in $todo_lists = TodoList::all();. Anyone could help me please?

Comment: By blank do you mean there is still some HTML output like your `h2` title "All Todo Lists"? Try doing a `var_dump` on your `$todo_list` in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
public function index()
{
    $todo_lists = TodoList::all();
    // to send variables into your view, use compact('var1', 'var2',...)
    return view('todos/index', compact('toto_lists'));
}
```

if you want to send a flash message:

```
return redirect('user/login')->with('message', 'Login Failed');
```

check: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rename

```
 protected $tabel = 'todo_lists';
```

to

```
 protected $table = 'todo_lists';
```